# Change attribute of twitter link

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, alter, data-url

I'm trying to change the data-url with jQuery. Currently my code looks like this.

```
<div id="twitterButton" title="Tweet it on Twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" id="tweet" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="" data-related="jasoncosta" data-lang="en" data-size="large" data-count="none">Tweet</a></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#twitterButton').click(function () {
        $('#tweet').attr("data-url", "https://www.google.com/");
    });
});</script>
```

As you can see I left the url-data blank so I could be sure it is only getting set in the jQuery. However whenever I click the tweet button it always opens the window with the link for the current page that I was on. Can someone explain how I can set it to be something else via jQuery or javascript?

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, you should consider marking it as 'accepted'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for controlling data attributes. As Daniele states in that answer, you must also stop the event propogation on the `a` element using [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

```
$('#twitterButton').click(function (e) {
    $('#tweet').data('url',"https://www.google.com");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Yeah this is a preferible approach, anyway it does not resolve the problem with the event propagation,
the Daniele Montes Solution is the right one!

Answer (score 3):

You must call the **preventDefault()** method to stop the propagation of the click event on the child **a** element:

Try this code:

```
$('#twitterButton').click(function (e) {
    $('#tweet').attr("data-url", "https://www.google.com/");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Good code

D.